# How to get whl file of Pillow module for AWS Glue python 3.7

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-imaging-library, aws-glue, python-module

I am trying to create thumbnails from s3 directory, the python script for the same is processed in AWS Glue. Please help me to create or find the whl file for the Pillow module in Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link will give the suitable whl files.

https://www.piwheels.org/simple/pillow-tools/